# relationship between cosets and commutators

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a normal subgroup of $H$, and let $x \in G$ and $y \in H$. Is it true that the following equation:

$$
xyG = yxG
$$

holds if and only if $[x,y] \in G$ ?, where $[x,y]$ is the commutator of $x$ and $y$, i.e. $[x,y]=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. If $xyG=yxG$, then there is a $g\in G$ such that $xy=yxg$, and therefore $[x,y]=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy=g\in G$. And if $[x,y]=g\in G$, then $xy=yxg$, so $xyG=yxgG=yxG$.

Answer (score 2):

Multiply both sides of the equation on the left by $x^{-1}y^{-1}$ to see that your equation is equivalent to $[x, y]G=G$, which is true iff $[x, y] \in G$.